# make pandas recognize a list containing column names the same of of the columns in its dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a list called x

```
x = ['Sales', 'Total', 'Quantity']
```

and I have an excel dataframe with columns named 'Employee', 'Age', 'Sex', 'Sales' , 'Quantity' and 'Total'.
How do I make pandas only pick the columns of the dataframe that have the same name as of those in the list?

Comment: `pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', usecols=x)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply choose the columns by doing:

```
df = df[x]
```

Comment: No, double square brackets won't work. `x` is already a list itself.

Comment: @QuangHoang you are right. should just take x only

Answer (score 2):

Just do:

```
x = ['Sales', 'Total', 'Quantity']

df = df[x]
```

Since `x` is already a list of columns, use it inside `single-brackets` to subset the dataframe.

**OR** use `Index.intersection`:

```
df = df[df.columns.intersection(x)]
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I only just began studying pandas so answers like these are very helpful

Answer (score 1):

```
 x = ['Sales', 'Total', 'Quantity']

 df.drop(columns=[col for col in df if col not in x], inplace=True)
```